# Why does the Earth move away from the Sun?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, solar-system, tidal-effect

From the ([Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_unit#Developments)) definition of the astronomical unit $AU$, we have that it is defined as:

$AU=\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{GMD^2}{k^2}}$

Where $k\approx0.01720209895$ is Gauss' gravitational constant, $G$ is Newton's gravitational constant, $M$ is the mass of the Sun and $D$ is the time period of one day. Therefore, [according to several observations](https://adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/2010IAUS..261..189A), pointing to an **increasing astronomical unit** at a tremendous pace (around $15$ cm a year), this means that the Sun is gaining approximately $6\times10^8$ kg per year (taking into account Sun's mass year losses).

**Questions:** (1) first of all, why does the distance from the Sun **increase** with Sun's mass augment? Shouldn't the gravitational attraction be stronger and attract the Earth more rapidly, instead of getting it away? And (2) how is this increment in the $AU$ explained? $6\times10^8$ kg per year seems unphysical.

Comment: The mass of the sun decreases  by converting mass to energy , it is not augmented, so the attractive force diminishes and the orbit grows,

Comment: Then is the formula wrong? Why does it exist then?

Comment: [Is Earth getting closer to the sun, or farther away?](https://www.livescience.com/is-earth-moving-closer-farther-sun)

Comment: Did you read in the Wikipedia article that “The Sun is constantly **losing mass** by radiating away energy, so the orbits of the planets are steadily **expanding** outward from the Sun”?

Comment: Gauss’ gravitational “constant” is something I (with a physics Ph.D.) had never even heard of. It depends on the mass of the Sun, which may explain your confusion.

Comment: That equation does not define the AU. It is currently defined as 149,597,870,700 meters, as the Wikipedia article explains. Thus the AU *does not change* as the Sun loses mass.

Comment: The astronomical unit is increasing, according to several papers. A good review is on the one from Anderson & Nieto (2010) I linked in the question: https://adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/2010IAUS..261..189A. Consult pages 4-6 of the PDF (192-194 of the journal version).

Comment: The definition of the AU was changed in 2012, after that paper was published, as you can read in Wikipedia. The radius of the Earth’s orbit is increasing. The AU is **not** increasing, according to the new definition. It is a fixed number of meters.

Comment: Oh! If you grab all you said in these comments, that seems like an answer! So the formula doesn't apply anymore!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of the confusion is contained in Gauss's gravitational constant $k$.  It's defined to be such that the equation you gave is true.  So the definition is really giving nothing more than a conversion between $AU$ and $k$.  You can't use this equation to calculate how far away earth will be when the mass of the sun changes or what the mass of the sun is given how far away the earth is; both $k$ and $AU$ would just be updated accordingly so that they both still have the relation given by your definition.

In actuality, $AU$ is now defined to be a specific distance that is not directly tied to the distance of the earth from the sun, even though of course it is approximately equal to it, and $k$ has been recommended to be discontinued in its use.